# Passportjs handle guest authentification for HTTP API

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Here is my code:

```
passport = require 'passport'
BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy

passport.use new BasicStrategy((username, pwd, done) ->
  console.log arguments
  if pwd is "1234" and username is "Foo"
    done undefined, {
      username: "Foo"
      role: "admin"
    }
  else done()
)


express = require("express")
app = express()

app.use express.logger()
app.use passport.initialize()
app.use passport.authenticate("basic", session: false)

app.get '/', (req, res) -> res.send req.user
```

**But with this way it works only when the user is authentificated using a header**.  When no authorization header is specified, I just get 401 on '/'. Is there a way to make authentification optional? Or a restful way to specify an authorization to say "Hi, I'm a guest"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `passport-http` middleware [will call `fail()` if `Authorization` header is missing](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/blob/f7ce8994e65c4ee7744588900d6092924209265e/lib/passport-http/strategies/basic.js#L69).

You could write your own authentication strategy, or fork and modify `passport-http`, or add a middleware that will add the header if missing, ie.

```
GUEST = "Basic #{new Buffer('guest:guest').toString('base64')}"
app.use (req, res, next) ->
  req.headers['authorization'] = GUEST unless req.headers['authorization']
  next()
```

You'll need to add this middleware before you call `app.use(passport...)`. Then in the strategy you could do eg.

```
passport.use new BasicStrategy (user, pass, done) ->
  if user == pass == 'guest'
    done null, {username: 'Guest'}
  else
    ...
```

Comment: in current version of Express.js  req.headers['Authorization']  will not work, use: req.get('Authorization')